In PhpStorm 2024.2 did not find with opened popup menu to create a file of selected type in current subdirectory
I moved to PhpStorm 2024.2 and when I have a file opened I see it full name of the file :

But what I did not find from prior version to open by right click possibilty with opened popup menu to create a file of selected type in current subdirectory.
Can I return such ftunctionality or maybe to open such  popup menu in some other way ?

It sounds like you want to right-click in a directory in the Project pane to create a file in that directory. If so, what does that image with the arrows have to do with anything? What happens when you right-click on a directory name in the Project pane?

Based on your arrows -- you are after the Navigation Bar. Just ensure it's enabled and placed at the top (it should now be at the bottom by default) -- https://imgur.com/qq4x7Q4 . Alternatively just use a shortcut to bring the floating version of it when needed -- Alt+Home here on Windows keymap. 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/new-ui.html#navigation_bar 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#navigate-with-navigation-bar 3) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#navigate-with-navigation-bar
